# Use cite in gnuplottex key

Tags: citing, gnuplot

I am using the [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) package to create plots with gnuplot from inline gnuplot code in my LaTeX documents. I am using `pdflatex` directly to get PDFs.

I would like to be able to use the `\cite` command within the gnuplottex instructions. I want to have the citations formatted the same way they are in the rest of my document.

This example illustrates what I would like to do:

> plot "data.csv" using 1:2 with lines title "\citet{Papale2006}"

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

**Update**: I am using the pdf terminal for gnuplottex.

Comment: Try with two backslashes instead of a single backslash.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this does not help. Also, when using "\citet{ABC}", the single backslash is preserved in the output. It shows up exactly like this in the output .pdf

Comment: My advice works with `latex` terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using the epslatex terminal mode for gnuplot:

> \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]

Works nicely with pdflatex and allows to use `\citet{ABC}` in the gnuplot key.

Comment: If your are using pdflatex anyway, you can think about switching from epslatex to cairolatex, which should generate pdfs out of the box, without eps as an intermediate step.